# Batch script for loop, variable not incrementing, need to copy/rename duplicate files

Tags: batch-file, copy, duplicates, rename

Im trying to copy css files from IE's cache folder to some folder in C:
The thing is theres lots of duplicates but I want to keep them all, so I made a batch script to copy all css files and add a counter/index variable to the beginning of each file. The problem is the variable is not incrementing and I dont know why? This is my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\*.css"') do (
set /a c=c+1
copy "%%A" "C:\Target\%c%_%%~nxA"
)
endlocal
```

Instead of some 30 css files being copied (I know this cuz I can see them in IE's cache folder) Im getting only about 10 copied and they just have "0_" appended at the front instead of an incrementing number (1-infinity).

I also tried !c! instead of %c% in the copy line part but it just adds literally "!c!" instead of the variables' value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are on the right track with `!c!`, but you need to use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` before your loop to activate the `!var!` syntax (delayed expansion)

Comment: Never mind i found out why! omg im so stupid. ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is supposed to be EnableDelayedExpansion! its case sensitive!! works now!! :)))

Comment: It is not case sensitive - you probably had a spelling error that you did not notice :) I like to use mixed case only for readability.

Comment: To increment you could just do `set /a c+=1`

Answer (score 0):

Not as fast (one dir per file copy), but get independent numeration for each css file

```
set source=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\*.css"') do (
    for /f %%C in ('dir /b "c:\target\*_%%~nxA" ^| find /c "_"') do (
        copy "%%A" "c:\target\%%C_%%~nxA"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did set `enabledelayedexpansion` but you are not using it in your loop. You should give this a try, this is what worked for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\*.css"') do (
set /a c=c+1
copy "%%A" "C:\Target\!c!_%%~nxA"
)
endlocal
```

The only difference is line 6 where I changed `%c%` to `!c!`.